# Can't run App on Note 2 because of too many images (only 20 images)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap

I am getting the following error when I go from my Main Activity page to my New Activity page. The New Activity page crashes unless it has <10 images or so, which is pathetic (the app runs fine emulated on my computer, however):

```
06-22 16:53:04.841 15058-15058/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-22 16:53:04.841 15058-15058/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e35c08)
06-22 16:53:04.851 15058-15058/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.matthewscompany.matthew.test1, PID: 15058
                                                   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
                                                       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3436)
                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:102)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1030)
                                                       at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
                                                       at com.example.matthew.test1.NewActivity.onCreate(NewActivity.java:23)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 16:53:04.861 2430-2769/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.matthewscompany.matthew.test1/com.example.matthew.test1.NewActivity
06-22 16:53:04.866 2430-2769/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.matthewscompany.matthew.test1/com.example.matthew.test1.MainActivity
```

I understand that the out of memory error occurs when the ram for a phone runs out when processing too many bitmaps.

Yes, I have read the Android Developer webpages on tips for processing bitmaps. However, I still don't understand which groups of code from their guides I'm supposed to insert, and where I'm supposed to insert it. I've tried inserting some of their stuff into my .java files but I just end up getting errors. I owe this to me being a beginner at Java and not understanding how to apply the example codes.

Again, I am a beginner to Java and Android Studio so please go easy on me and explain things as simply as you can, if possible.

Here's my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.matthew.test1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//Main Menu

    //Main Activity Mario Icon:

    ImageButton Mario;
    ImageButton Luigi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Mario= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Mario);

        Mario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);

            }
        });

       Luigi= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Luigi);

        Luigi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);


            }
        });
    }



}
```

NewActivity.java:

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    Button next;
    Button previous;
    TextView pageCounter;
    int count = 1;
    private static final int TOTAL_IMG_COUNT = 23;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        pageCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        pageCounter.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        previous.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == next) {
            viewFlipper.showNext();
            if (next.getId() == (R.id.ImageView23)) {
                count = 1;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
            pageCounter.setText(String.valueOf(count) + "/" + TOTAL_IMG_COUNT);
        }
        else if (v == previous) {
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            if(previous.getId() == (R.id.ImageView1)) {
                count = TOTAL_IMG_COUNT;
            } else {
                count--;
            }
            pageCounter.setText(String.valueOf(count) + "/" + TOTAL_IMG_COUNT);
        }
    }
}
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.matthew.test1.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Mario"
        android:src="@drawable/mario_select"
        android:layout_above="@+id/samus_select"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/samus_select"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/samus_select" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Luigi"
        android:src="@drawable/luigi_select"
        android:layout_above="@+id/samus_select"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dk_select"
        android:src="@drawable/dk_select"
        android:layout_above="@+id/falcon_select"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/link_select"
        android:src="@drawable/link_select"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fox_select"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/samus_select"
        android:src="@drawable/samus_select"
        android:layout_above="@+id/kirby_select"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/falcon_select"
        android:src="@drawable/falcon_select"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/samus_select"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ness_select"
        android:src="@drawable/ness_select"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/yoshi_select"
        android:src="@drawable/yoshi_select"
        android:layout_below="@+id/falcon_select"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/kirby_select"
        android:src="@drawable/kirby_select"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pika_select"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/samus_select"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/samus_select" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fox_select"
        android:src="@drawable/fox_select"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Luigi"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pika_select"
        android:src="@drawable/pika_select"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/kirby_select"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/kirby_select" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/jiggly_select"
        android:src="@drawable/jiggly_select"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yoshi_select"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/yoshi_select"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/yoshi_select" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Hitbox64"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="48dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Mario"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_new.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.matthew.test1.NewActivity">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="480dp"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b1"/>

        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
             android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             android:src="@drawable/b2"/>

         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView3"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b3"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView4"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b4"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView5"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView6"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b6"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView7"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b7"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView8"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b8"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView9"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b9"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView10"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b10"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView11"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b11"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView12"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b12"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView13"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b13"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView14"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b14"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView16"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b17"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView18"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b18"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView19"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b19"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView20"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b20"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView21"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b21"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView22"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b22"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView23"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/b23"/>

    </ViewFlipper>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prev"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/next"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Frame Counter"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Bair"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/previous"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As @Vucko said in the answer below, the drawables you set in the activity_new.xml might be more high-res than necessary. Perhaps you could scale them down (I just use Paint for this task), or you could load a scaled version of them. That way you can still load higher resolutions when you need them. You said you already checked the Developer pages, but I would still recommand trying this: [link](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 1):

If your images are too high-resolution, they can eat up a **LOT** of memory, especially if you have 20 of them as you say. Consider using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or some other library to load your images.